# Insert MySQL row on server start

Tags: mysql, debian, boot, init, runlevel

I have a debian based private server and am wondering, what's the best way to insert a row to database when the server boots. I am trying to show it in the notifications on my PHP-based monitoring site.

I currently am thinking of a simple script(have not decided on the language yet) running just once on start-up and terminating afterwards. Are there any better solutions out there?

EDIT:
I used scripts in init.d folder to be run on different runlevels. Currently, the only one I have gotten to work, is the bash script that inserts a row about the server booting up. This is under rcS.d/.

The problem is, that when I use the same method to run a script while the runlevels are 0 or 6, for example, the script is never run. I think it might be a priority issue. Look at the picture below (The priority is the same as the kill priorities for apache, etc...). Are the scripts run in alphabetical order or could I bump all priorities up by one somehow?

[image: The priority is the same as the kill priorities for apache, etc...]

Comment: You can insert this line into the crontab `@reboot /var/www/myserverrebooted.php`

Comment: Edited the question with details.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a built-in option to execute an SQL file on start, which sounds like what you want:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file

The other thing you can do is just review the server uptime periodically and either compare it to a known value or just check that it recently rebooted.

Your most recent idea to use a startup script also has merit, the problem is you need to ensure it runs *after* mysql has started.  S01 is a priority/order, so you want to put in a number bigger than MySQL.

Depending on what distribution you are using, that number may not apply though if the system is using upstart or systemd and it's a big more complex.

The crontab @reboot suggestion is also a good one.

Comment: worth noting that init-file would also run on mysql restart, due to upgrade etc.

Comment: also data about a server restarting is also stored in /var/run/wtmp (run 'last' on the console')

Comment: Also be aware that commands in any such `init-file` would run with unrestricted privileges—so be **very careful** that they cannot be maliciously modified.